# I am unable to add an image to a Tkinter button

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

I am using the following to add a button to my GUI. I am not able to get the image to display. Without specifying height or width, the button is huge but no image.  Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?  All of my other buttons, created similarly but with no image are displayed fine.

```
photo = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\jim\Pictures\refresh.png")
self.bt_plot_test1 = tk.Button(self.lf_FileFunctions, image = photo, command=self.plot_employee_allocations)
self.bt_plot_test1.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=0, pady=0,sticky=tk.NW)
```

Comment: img = r"C:\Users\jim\Pictures\refresh.png"
           photo = PhotoImage(file=img )

Comment: It does, thanks!  Just needed to use 'self.photo'.  Having a heck of a time positioning the button in a frame, but that's another issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code for your purpose:

```
#Import necessary modules
from tkinter import *

#Create an instance
wn = Toplevel()
wn.title("Rounded Button")

#Create window
wn.geometry("700x300")

#Create button function
def my_func():
   print("Button has been clicked.")

#Import the image
photo = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\jim\Pictures\refresh.png")

img_label= Label(image=photo)

button= Button(wn, image= photo,command= my_func,
borderwidth=0)
button.pack(pady=30)

wn.mainloop()
```

If the image is large, then, you may face trouble with displaying the image in a button. So, in the above code, we add the image to a label and then display the label over the button. We then set the borderwidth parameter to zero to hide the button border.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question "Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?"